# use 2 tableviews in the same view controller (swift3)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, row, cell

My code below is a typical tableview. What I would like to do is have two tableviews with there respective cells cell and dx both display the var text. I tried combining things using "return cell && cc" but that is not working. I just want to be able to use to separate cells within 2 different tableviews to display the same variable in the same view controller.

```
        import UIKit

var text = ["a", "b"]

var row = 0

class ViewController: UIViewController,  UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var b: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var a: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == a {


           return 5
        }
        else {

            return 10
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == a {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
            return cell
        }
        else {
            let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "dx")
            return cell

        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
row = indexPath.row
}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use two tableview as follows:->

**IBOutlet**

```
@IBOutlet var table1: UITableView!
@IBOutlet var table2: UITableView!
```

**UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if tableView == table1 {
        return 5
    }
    else {
        return 10
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView == table1 {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell1")
        return cell

    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code with your suggestion it builds. However the var text is not being displayed on either of the textviews.

Comment: You code suggestions are reflected in my edited question above.

Answer (score 0):

**UITableViewDataSource**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     var count:Int?

     if tableView == self.tblGuests {
        count = 2
     }

     if tableView == self.tblDetail{
        count =  5
     }

     return count!

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell:UITableViewCell?

        if tableView == self.tblGuests {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookingGuestsCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingGuestsCell
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookingRoomDetailCell", for: indexPath) as! BookingRoomDetailCell
        }
        return cell!
}
```